# Can't connect to Twitter API in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, oauth, twitter

I'm trying to connect to the Twitter API via an AS3 app, but I keep getting

`Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`

When I try `URLRequest("https://api.twitter.com/oauth")` it at least loads something and calls my `Event.COMPLETE` listener. Can Flash just not connect to the Twitter API without a third-party? I have tried numerous AS3 OAuth packages and keep getting the same thing.

`edit` and I'm using `Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.twitter.com/crossdomain.xml");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Twitter restricts flash requests to originate from twitter.com. You should be able to run a proxy the request on your own server to bypass the restriction.

http://api.twitter.com/crossdomain.xml

http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/28232e3965222037